# ¿Como crear una carpeta en la Storage de Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Mi problema trato de crear un pequeño **script** que me permita crear una **carpeta** y dentro de esta un archivo (jpg) en la **Storage** de **Firebase**. Encontré en la [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664385/how-to-create-a-folder-in-firebase-storage) que con solo colocar el nombre de la carpeta antes del nombre del archivo esta se debe generar, pero no se genera y ni se carga el archivo. Solo se carga el **archivo** cuando yo manualmente creo la **carpeta** en la **Storage**.

Mi código de carga:

```
public function upload(){
        $this->bucket->upload(
            file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']),
            [
                'name' => "ena/" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']
            ]
        );
    }
```

Estoy usando la librería de [Kreait](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage-example). **Gracias** y espero su apoyo.

Comment: Citando lo que dices: *Encontré en la web que con solo colocar el nombre de la carpeta antes del nombre del archivo esta se debe generar, pero no se genera y ni se carga el archivo.*... por qué no pones el código de cómo lo haces?  La idea de esta página es corregir los errores que tienes

Comment: Hola amigo gracias, pero ya coloque mi método de carga donde coloco el directorio antes del nombre del archivo e incluso adjunte los enlaces de la web de donde extraje la información.